# Excel dynamic cell reference

Tags: excel

Example Pic:
[image]

Hi,
I am referring "check1" book. total count of check1 is 15. I have check2,check3,check4 etc having different counts. So in my formula (=[check1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$C$15)  "C" should get the dynamic number based on "A1" cell. If A1 cell having 23 count then my formula should get =[check1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$C$23.  Is it possible to get the dynamic reference?
I hope my ques is clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `INDEX` yet?

Comment: `=[check1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX([check1xls]Sheet1!$C:$C,$A$1)`

Comment: I tried with Indirect function. Its working.. cool.. @DarrenBartrup-Cook :-)

Comment: @Manoj `INDEX` is preferable to `INDIRECT`, since `INDIRECT` is [volatile](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function).